# Cryptic PHP error invloving Zend Framework and Doctrine

Tags: apache, zend-framework, doctrine, suphp, litespeed

I'm currently receiving the following error message with Zend Framework and Doctrine. I'm trying to figure out how to solve this issue..

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'LogicException' with message 'Passed array does not specify an existing static method (class 'Doctrine' does not have a method 'modelsAutoload')' in /home/bellalun/library/Smallunch/lib/Bootstrap.php:173 Stack trace: #0 /home/bellalun/library/Smallunch/lib/Bootstrap.php(173): spl_autoload_register(Array) #1 /etc/ZendFramework/1.9.0/Zend/Application/Bootstrap/BootstrapAbstract.php(660): Bootstrap->_initDoctrine() #2 /etc/ZendFramework/1.9.0/Zend/Application/Bootstrap/BootstrapAbstract.php(613): Zend_Application_Bootstrap_BootstrapAbstract->_executeResource('doctrine') #3 /etc/ZendFramework/1.9.0/Zend/Application/Bootstrap/BootstrapAbstract.php(577): Zend_Application_Bootstrap_BootstrapAbstract->_bootstrap(NULL) #4 /etc/ZendFramework/1.9.0/Zend/Application.php(324): Zend_Application_Bootstrap_BootstrapAbstract->bootstrap() #5 /home/bellalun/application/bootstrap.php(14): Zend_Application->bootstrap() #6 /home/bellalun/public_html/dev.php(8): require('/home/bellalun/...') #7 {main} thrown in /home/bellalun/library/Smallunch/lib/Bootstrap.php on line 173

Here's what's on line 173

```
    $this->getApplication()->getAutoloader()
                       ->pushAutoloader(array('Doctrine', 'autoload'));
spl_autoload_register(array('Doctrine', 'modelsAutoload'));
$manager = Doctrine_Manager::getInstance();
$manager->setAttribute(Doctrine_Core::ATTR_AUTO_ACCESSOR_OVERRIDE, true);
```

My hosting company made some changes over the weekend that messed up a few of my sites, taking them down. They switched me from Apache to LiteSpeed and my PHP handler from DSO to SuPHP. Not sure if this is related or not..

Answer (score 1):

I don't use Doctrine, but the code sample you've posted doesn't make a lot of sense. On the first line you're registering Doctrine's autoload function with the ZF autoloader. This looks good, and seems to [match this tutorial](http://www.mwop.net/blog/220-Autoloading-Doctrine-and-Doctrine-entities-from-Zend-Framework.html). On the next line, you're registering another autoloader with SPL directly (this is bad), and doing so using another, apparently non-existent function (modelsAutoload). Since this is the line that's erroring I'd guess commenting that line out will fix your problem.